# SQL query with multiple table joins that interjoins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I'm new to this place, though I think I've used solutions from here before.

I'm a bit dusty in webprogramming and just took it up again and for some reason I always seem to get the best nightmares...

Anyway my problem is this:

I have 7 tables that I need to join together but not all on the same table.
They look something like this:

---

caravan_rarity

id---tier---type---chance_interval_start---chance_interval_end---trade_multiplier

---

caravan_size

id---tier---size---stop_points---guard----diversity---price_first---price_increase---trade_multiplier

---

caravan_stop

id---fk_stop_one---fk_stop_two---fk_stop_three

---

city_other_known

id---name---fk_city_size_id---fk_city_relation_id---distance---upgrade_relation

---

city_relation

id---tier---relation---trade_multiplier

---

city_size

id---tier---size---lost_revenue---base_trade_value---population_range_min---population_range_max---trade_multiplier

---

fogcity_caravan

id---fk_caravan_size_id---fk_city_start---fk_caravan_stop_id---fk_city_end---fk_caravan_rarity_id

---

Anyplace where the column name is something with fk, that's a foreign key linking to the column with the same name without fk (example: fk_caravan_size_id links to caravan_size.id)

The exception is in caravan_stop table. All the fk columns there links to city_other_known.id.
Also in fogcity_caravan the fk_city_start and fk_city_end both links to city_other_known.id

Another note: The only comlumns allowed to be NULL is caravan_stop.fk_stop_one, caravan_stop.fk_stop_two and caravan_stop.fk_stop_three

And so we come to my attempt at a query for all this:

```
SELECT 
    caravan_size.size, 
    caravan_size.diversity, 
    caravan_size.trade_multiplier, 
    city_other_known.name, 
    city_size.trade_multiplier, 
    city_relation.relation, 
    city_relation.trade_multiplier, 
    caravan_rarity.type, 
    caravan_rarity.trade_multiplier
FROM fogcity_caravan 
INNER JOIN caravan_size ON fogcity_caravan.fk_caravan_size_id = caravan_size.id 
INNER JOIN caravan_stop ON fogcity_caravan.fk_caravan_stop_id = caravan_stop.id 
INNER JOIN city_other_known ON fogcity_caravan.fk_city_start = city_other_known.id 
       AND fogcity_caravan.fk_city_end = city_other_known.id 
       AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_one = city_other_known.id 
       AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_two = city_other_known.id 
       AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_three = city_other_known.id 
INNER JOIN caravan_rarity ON fogcity_caravan.fk_caravan_rarity_id = caravan_rarity.id 
INNER JOIN city_size ON city_other_known.fk_city_size_id = city_size.id 
INNER JOIN city_relation ON city_other_known.fk_city_relation_id = city_relation.id
```

---

And... as some of you might be able to see already (I have no clue weather or not this is obvious) I get a return of 0 rows.

Please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about changing inner join to left join?

Comment: Try with replacing the `And` with `OR` in `city_other_know` join condition

Answer (score 0):

Find the tables on the left side that there is a possibility of a match on the right side and use `LEFT JOIN`. And for those that will have definite match use `INNER JOIN`.

See link [here.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

For example you could probably LEFT JOIN here:

```
 LEFT JOIN city_other_known ON fogcity_caravan.fk_city_start = city_other_known.id 
   AND fogcity_caravan.fk_city_end = city_other_known.id 
   AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_one = city_other_known.id 
   AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_two = city_other_known.id 
   AND caravan_stop.fk_stop_three = city_other_known.id
```

And use OR instead of AND:

```
LEFT JOIN city_other_known ON fogcity_caravan.fk_city_start = city_other_known.id 
   OR fogcity_caravan.fk_city_end = city_other_known.id 
   OR caravan_stop.fk_stop_one = city_other_known.id 
   OR caravan_stop.fk_stop_two = city_other_known.id 
   OR caravan_stop.fk_stop_three = city_other_known.id
```